# How to clear REDO Actions in Microsoft.interop.Word?

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-word, office-interop

Working on Word Addin and in this when actions taken no undo action is display but only redo action is display in word so any I am looking forward to know how we clear redo list in Microsoft.interop.Word ?

Answer (score 2):

You can clear the undo history which will also clean the redo history, if there is any:

```
ActiveDocument.UndoClear()
```

Note that after clearing the undo/redo history you will still be able to repeat the last command by pressing Ctrl+Y.

Comment: I have already use undo clear but still it's redo button is enable.